# unable to get rid off the ending tag of img element while creating img element under div element

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to add some elements dynamically using javascript DOM. I'm successfully creating the elements with javascript DOM which must have ending tag. I don't know how to create an element which does not have ending tag like img element.

Here's how i am doing this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function add(){
var myImg = document.createElement("img");
    myImg.setAttribute("src","c:\abc.png");
    myImg.setAttribute("width","20");
    myImg.setAttribute("height","20");

    var myDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    myDiv.appendChild(myImg);
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="mydiv">
<button onclick="add();">Add</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

By doing this, it creates the IMG element with ending tag too. See below what i am talking about.

```
<img src="c:\abc.png" width="20" height="20"></img> //Incorrect(Ending tag available)
```

This is what i want:

```
<img src="c:\abc.png" width="20" height="20">
```

Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: There are no tags in DOM. Whatever you see is just an interpretation by the developer tools.

Comment: You're just seeing the handiwork of the browser as it shows you the DOM as synthetic HTML.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for help. Now i understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're creating this with JavaScript, you're probably looking at the developer console to see the code (such as closing tags). That's all generated by the browser and includes fixes the browser makes to your code. You shouldn't worry about this, since it's mostly out of your control.